# How to add Icon to JPanel

Tags: java, swing

So this is going to be very basic, but I can't figure it out. I have a CarIcon, which implements an Icon interface and a Resizable interface (I'll be implementing that later) and I have everything set up, but I can't figure out how to add my icon in to the JPanel or JFrame from main. I mean, I don't have the Component and Graphics information in order to call paintIcon method in my CarIcon class, so what do I do?

Here's some relevant code:

CarIcon

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class CarIcon implements Icon, Resizable{

    private int width;
    /**
     * Construct a car of a given width.
     * @param width: the width of the car
     */
    public CarIcon(int aWidth){
        width = aWidth;
    }
    public int getIconWidth(){
        return width;
    }
    public int getIconHeight(){
        return width/2;
    }

    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Rectangle2D.Double body = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y + width / 6, width -1, width / 6);
        Ellipse2D.Double frontTire = new Ellipse2D.Double(x + width / 6, y + width / 3, width / 6, width /6);
        Ellipse2D.Double rearTire = new Ellipse2D.Double(x + width * 2 / 3, y + width / 3, width / 6, width / 6);

        // The bottom of the front windshield
        Point2D.Double r1 = new Point2D.Double(x + width / 6, y + width / 6);
        // The front of the roof
        Point2D.Double r2 = new Point2D.Double(x + width / 3, y);
        // The rear of the roof
        Point2D.Double r3 = new Point2D.Double(x + width * 2 / 3, y);
        // The bottom of the rear windshield
        Point2D.Double r4 = new Point2D.Double(x + width * 5 /6, y + width / 6);

        Line2D.Double frontWindshield = new Line2D.Double(r1, r2);
        Line2D.Double roofTop = new Line2D.Double(r2, r3);
        Line2D.Double rearWindshield = new Line2D.Double(r3, r4);

        g2.fill(frontTire);
        g2.fill(rearTire);
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.fill(body);
        g2.draw(frontWindshield);
        g2.draw(roofTop);
        g2.draw(rearWindshield);

    }
    @Override
    public void resize(int y) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        width += y;
    }
    @Override
    public void setIconWidth(int x) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        width = x;
    }

}
```

SliderTester (main)

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class SliderTester extends JPanel{

    private static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 200;
    final static Icon myCar = new CarIcon(20);
    final static JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);

         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

Thanks for your help in advance and Happy Easter!

The following won't work:

```
final static Icon myCar = new CarIcon(20);
final static JLabel label = new JLabel(myCar);
```

Compiler says "The constructor JLabel(Icon) is undefined"

Another edit:
Can there be something wrong with my Eclipse? Here is a screen shot where I take your code and paste it in my program and it throws an error:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Icons don't naturally go into JPanels, but they **do** naturally and easily go into JLabels, and then JLabels can easily go into a JPanel, and I think that this is exactly what you should do:

- Create a JLabel with your Icon. You can do this either by passing the Icon into the JLabel's constructor or by calling `setIcon(...)` on the JLabel.
- Add your JLabel to your JPanel using whatever appropriate layout manager you need
- Add that JPanel to another JPanel or to a top level window or wherever it needs to go.

If you've implemented your Icon appropriately, you'd do something like:

```
JLabel myLabel = new JLabel(myIcon);
myPanel.add(myLabel);
```

Or for example with your code:

```
  JLabel label = new JLabel(myCar);
  panel.add(label);

  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  frame.setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
  frame.add(panel);
```

Or more simply:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new CarIcon(40));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(label);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
     }
  });
}
```

---

Here's my whole test program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestCarIcon {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(new CarIcon(80));
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(label);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
         }
      });
   }

}

class CarIcon implements Icon, Resizable {

   private int width;

   /**
    * Construct a car of a given width.
    * 
    * @param width
    *           : the width of the car
    */
   public CarIcon(int aWidth) {
      width = aWidth;
   }

   public int getIconWidth() {
      return width;
   }

   public int getIconHeight() {
      return width / 2;
   }

   public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

      // !! Added to smooth images
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      Rectangle2D.Double body = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y + width / 6,
            width - 1, width / 6);
      Ellipse2D.Double frontTire = new Ellipse2D.Double(x + width / 6, y
            + width / 3, width / 6, width / 6);
      Ellipse2D.Double rearTire = new Ellipse2D.Double(x + width * 2 / 3, y
            + width / 3, width / 6, width / 6);

      // The bottom of the front windshield
      Point2D.Double r1 = new Point2D.Double(x + width / 6, y + width / 6);
      // The front of the roof
      Point2D.Double r2 = new Point2D.Double(x + width / 3, y);
      // The rear of the roof
      Point2D.Double r3 = new Point2D.Double(x + width * 2 / 3, y);
      // The bottom of the rear windshield
      Point2D.Double r4 = new Point2D.Double(x + width * 5 / 6, y + width / 6);

      Line2D.Double frontWindshield = new Line2D.Double(r1, r2);
      Line2D.Double roofTop = new Line2D.Double(r2, r3);
      Line2D.Double rearWindshield = new Line2D.Double(r3, r4);

      g2.fill(frontTire);
      g2.fill(rearTire);
      g2.setColor(Color.RED);
      g2.fill(body);
      g2.draw(frontWindshield);
      g2.draw(roofTop);
      g2.draw(rearWindshield);

   }

   @Override
   public void resize(int y) {
      width += y;
   }

   @Override
   public void setIconWidth(int x) {
      width = x;
   }

}

interface Resizable {
   void resize(int y);

   void setIconWidth(int x);
}
```

Which shows this:

[image]

Comment: Hmm would you mind elaborating a bit? I run into the same problem with the JLabel that I do the JPanel. I can't simply go label.add(myCar). Is there some work around that I am missing. My car isn't an image, (it implements interface Icon).

Comment: Also, panel.setIcon(myCar) won't work because it only works for the Java swing Icon and casting it throws an exception.

Comment: @aurora91: to set a JLabel's Icon you must do one of two things: You can do this either by passing the Icon into the JLabel's constructor or by calling `setIcon(...)` on the JLabel. If you've implemented the interface correctly, the JLabel should handle it fine.

Comment: That's the issue, neither of those options work. I edited my original post to demonstrate how I'm adding Icon to the JLabel's constructor and what error it's giving. setIcon() won't work either since my Icon isn't from the Java swing library. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @aurora91: it makes not one bit of difference if it is your icon class or Swing's as **it implements from java.awt.Icon** so it will work. Look at my last bit of code, and test it. Again, it works. Seriously.

Comment: Sorry that I keep endlessly bothering you. But it's seriously not working. I added in a screenshot of your code in  my program to show that it won't work for me. It says the constructor is undefined.

Comment: @aurora91: what error are you seeing? Please post the whole message. I've also posted an image of what I see when I run the program.

Comment: "The constructor JLabel(CarIcon) is undefined" and then suggests to remove the argument from JLabel. And yes, that's the image that I'm trying to get. After that, I want to be able to resize it with a slide bar. But as you can see, I can't even get it to appear.

Comment: @aurora91: then something else is wrong. Your CarIcon class extends the Icon interface right? You don't happen to have your own Icon interface lurking in that package do you?

Comment: @aurora91: no, you should not. Your class is implementing **your** interface, and JLabel will not recognize that, but rather will only recognize classes that implement the `java.awt.Icon` interface. Delete your Icon interface. As a general rule, try to avoid giving your classes, interfaces, enums names that clash with names found in core Java.

Comment: Yeah I can be a bit of a derp sometimes... Sorry.

Comment: @aurora91: you're in good company and are welcome to join my derp club.